# How to translate a lambda expression to normal code?

Tags: java, for-loop, java-stream

I was writing in java 1.8 and now I need to downgrade to 1.6. I have a problem writing this code in the normal way. Any suggestions?

```
return Stream.of(field.getText().split(","))
             .map(String::trim)
             .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())**
             .map(Integer::valueOf)
             .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

That is what I tried:

```
if(!splitted[i].isEmpty()) {
   set.add(Integer.valueOf(splitted[i]));
}
```

Comment: You should not use such old java version.

Comment: you can start by iterating over the result of `field.getText().split(",")`, the `filter` could be replaced by if statement, the `map` with a function call.

Comment: Yess i know @Jens but i need too. Some of the computers are running java 1.6

Comment: Thanks @NaderHajlaoui, thats what i start doing, but stuck on the .map

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Set<Integer> results = new HashSet<>();
for (String part : field.getText().split(",")) {
    String trimmed = part.trim();
    if (trimmed.isEmpty()) continue;
    results.add(Integer.valueOf(trimmed));
}
```

Comment: Thank you @DDovzhenko. Is this wrong ? I updated my question.

Comment: @AristotelisPozidis you forgot to trim values in your part.

Answer (score 3):

Your code does the following:

1. split the text of field along ','
2. call trim() on each of these
3. only work on all those which are not empty
4. parse this Strings to Integers
5. put them in a Set

this could be done like this:

*EDIT*: for-each is nicer and can be used since java 1.5

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
for(String split : field.getText().split(",")) {
    split = split.trim();
    if(!split.isEmpty()) {
         set.add(Integer.valueOf(split));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @DerMolly, i updated my question is it corrent?

Comment: You need to create something that implements Set, I used HashSet for example

Comment: Yes thank you very much for your help. @DerMolly Now its working as expected